# TSLint unhappy with non-alphabetized import sources

Tags: typescript, tslint, tsx

I have a couple of TypeScript import sources that TSLint is unhappy about, because they are apparently not alphabetized.

```
import { DialogNoConfigurationFile } from './view/dialogs/dialog-no-configuration-file';
import { DisplayMain } from './view/display/display-main';
import { Global } from './business/global';
import { remote } from 'electron';
import { RequestResponse } from './data/model/request-response';
import { UserRequestResponse } from './data/model/user-request-response';
```

The error message from TSLint:

```
ERROR: /home/myuser/Documents/myproject/administration2/src/app.tsx:11:1 - Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
ERROR: /home/myuser/Documents/myproject/administration2/src/app.tsx:12:1 - Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
```

My package.json script command:

```
"lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --force"
```

Even though TSLint is unhappy about `Global` and `remote`, everything is ok with alphabetization. I believe TSLint must be unhappy about the capitalization or something similar. Is there anyway to check how TSLint is alphabetizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run tslint with `--fix` to sort the imports:

```
npx tslint --fix --project tsconfig.json src/app.tsx
```

And if you use VS Code, there's a tslint extension that allows you to apply individual fixes.

Assuming you use the default settings for the `ordered-imports` rule, your imports should be okay when sorted like this: (absolute before relative)

```
import { remote } from 'electron';
import { Global } from './business/global';
import { RequestResponse } from './data/model/request-response';
import { UserRequestResponse } from './data/model/user-request-response';
import { DialogNoConfigurationFile } from './view/dialogs/dialog-no-configuration-file';
import { DisplayMain } from './view/display/display-main';
```

For more importation you can check the documentation of the rule at https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/:

> If no "groups" options is set, a default grouping is used of third-party, parent directories and the current directory. ("bar", "../baz", "./foo".)